# Receiving data sent from AIR app in node.js server running on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, air

I am trying to receive data sent from my client adobe air application in node.js server running on Heroku, but with no success.

This is how i am sending the data:

```
    var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:5000");

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    variables.data = 'this is data';

    request.data = variables;

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onRestaurantObjectLoadComplete);
    loader.load(request);
```

And my Node.js code for receiving requests :

```
app.get('/',function (request, res) {
console.log("received request data" + request.data );
});
app.listen(port, function() {
console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

The requests come to the server, and i am able to send the answer to the client, but data is always undefined.

Also, if i try to send data using POST method i get a Stream error in AIR application.

What would be the correct way of sending data to node.js server from AIR application?

EDIT: I managed to make it work locally, but when i upload it to heroku, it doesnt work.
I am sending the request to http://: (same as i did locally but myHerokuApp.com was localhost) and i keep getting a stream error. 
What would have to be the correct URL to send requests to?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it only does not work on the Simulator, once on testing on a real device it will work with the URL given by Heroku.

Still don't know how to make it work on the Simulator though.